# "The system cannot find the path specified" error in WebStorm and meteor.js

Tags: meteor, ide, webstorm

I am programming using Meteor.js and the IDE am using is WebStorm; whenever I hit run in WebStorm I get this kind of error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I don't know how to fix it. I've tried to visit the paths that are in the WebStorm output, but I found `meteor.bat` & `runnerw.exe`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\forland\AppData\Local\.meteor\meteor.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you correctly followed the [Running and debugging a Meteor application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/using-meteor.html#installMeteor) instructions in the WebStorm help guide?  It sounds like WebStorm is not able to find the meteor executable.

Here are some other resources that could help.

- [Run/Debug Configuration: Meteor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-meteor.html)
- [Languages and Frameworks: Meteor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/meteor.html)

Also, try running your meteor project outside of WebStorm to make sure you don't have a meteor executable problem.

- From the command line, browse to your meteor project's folder.
- Run the project

  ```
  meteor run
  ```

Update your question if you get an errors or have more information after trying these resources.

Comment: What is the error? Looks like your comment was submitted before you pasted the error.

Comment: after applying his instructions, it worked the error got gone The system cannot find the path specified.
 But when i run the main.html i got the webpage, but i got blank_webpage. When i inspected that that page, I saw an error message that says 
--> meteor npm install --save babel-runtime.  and  I did using cmd. First, i went to project folder\simple-todo then i install ;but i still cannot display my webpage

Comment: Well, i figured the problem; i was supposed to close webstom when i install